# Brainstorm: a pun on rainstorm?

Tags: etymology, puns, portmanteau-words

The Online Etymology Dictionary unsurprisingly says *[brainstorm](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=brainstorm)* is from the combination of *brain* and *storm*.

What I want to know is whether or not this neologism was an intentional pun on the word *[rainstorm](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=rainstorm)* and also whether or not, when people use *brainstorm* today, they think of it as a pun or an independent word from *rainstorm*.

I, for one, used *brainstorm* my entire life without thinking about *rainstorm* until last week when, as if in a thunderous mental flash, it suddenly occurred to me. Am I just late to make an obvious connection here? Or is this news to other people as well?

Comment: Does 1849 count as a neologism?

Comment: I might be misusing "neologism." I meant that it was a linguistic novelty at the time it was coined, but all words are that, aren't they? Probably not a neologism then--point taken!

Comment: It originally referred to an epileptic fit, but the OED doesn't say whether or not it was a pun.

Comment: Re "is this news to other people as well?", [google for rainstorm brainstorm](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=+rainstorm++brainstorm+&oq=+rainstorm++brainstorm+&gs_l=hp.12..0i10i30.1285.1285.1.2435.1.1.0.0.0.0.132.132.0j1.1.0...0.0...1c.fIPejtjAMw0&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=2950534a978e6727&biw=1003&bih=556) gets very few hits, so yeah, probably news.

Comment: So you just had a brainstorm about a potential etymology?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer appears to be that there is no evidence that *brainstorm* is a pun on *rainstorm*. As mentioned in the comments, it was originally used to denote '*a violent transient fit of insanity*', and according to Webster, [that remains its primary definition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/brainstorm).

Elaborating on the transition to its present meaning, [Ken Greenwald (Fort Collins, CO - U.S.A.) quotes](http://www.wordwizard.com/phpbb3/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=4733) from the book, [*America in So Many Words*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0395860202):

> BRAINSTORM: Originally a brainstorm was a momentary malfunction of the
>   mind, a ‘cerebral disturbance,’ in the words of an 1894 investigator.
>   A bright idea was not yet ‘a brainstorm’ but a ‘brain wave,’ as far
>   back as “Harper’s” magazine of 1890: ‘*Lucilla, with what she was fond
>   of terming a brain wave, comprehended the situation.*’ But by the 1920s
>   ‘brain wave’ was subsiding, while ‘brainstorm’ took over the meaning
>   of ‘a sudden surge of ingenuity.’
>
> The first instance of this transferred sense, ‘*He had a brainstorm*,’
>   is recorded in the magazine ‘College Humor’ in early 1925. Many
>   brainstorms took place after that, such as this one from 1941: ‘*Then I
>   had the brainstorm of getting an English star like Howard to play the
>   part*,’ and another from 1993: ‘*Then one of the guys working here had
>   a brainstorm.*’

As the OP has noted, Etymonline [fails to provide](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=brainstorm) any additional insight:

> "brilliant idea, mental excitement, fit of mental application," 1849, *from brain (n.) + figurative use of storm (n.)*. As a verb, recorded from 1920s.

It is, however, interesting to note a curious discrepancy in the OED in its [native](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/brainstorm) and [American English](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/brainstorm) definitions for *brainstorming*. The former defines it as:

> 1. **British informal** a moment in which one is suddenly unable to think
>      clearly or act sensibly: *we can only assume that someone simply had a
>      brainstorm and left the important bits out*
> 2. a spontaneous group discussion to produce ideas and ways of solving problems: *the participants held a brainstorm*
>
>    1. [as modifier]: *brainstorm exercises*
>
>       **North American informal** a sudden clever idea: *these three brainstorms
>         may flop like other well-intentioned innovations*

IOW, the primary and secondary definitions are more or less contradictory. The AE definition also lists both definitions, but in reverse order. Webster similarly lists these contradictory views:

> 2a : a sudden bright idea
>
> 2b : a harebrained idea

(with 1, of course, being about transient fits of insanity.)

Comment: I've never heard `brainstorm` either to mean "a sudden clever idea" (if anything, those are called `brainwaves`) or "a sudden inability to think clearly" (those being called, for better or worse, `brainfarts`).